# Visual Studio: Errors only showing in terminal after running code

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, terminal

No errors are shown in the "problems" tab nor in the code itself. How do I get these errors to show up in the "problems" tab and in my code for easier debugging?

Right now it says "No problems have been detected in the workspace." When my code runs with errors in the terminal.

I tried reinstalling and resetting my settings, no luck.

error example (only shown in terminal):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "redacted", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "redacted", line 6, in main
    deal_cards(deck, numcards)
  File "redacted", line 17, in deal_cards
    if number > len(deck):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @tymtam added in post

Answer (score 0):

The error you show is a runtime error (an error that happens when a program is run, not before) and the Errors window doesn't show runtime errors.